# Difference between reading files client-side and server-side

Tags: javascript, php

What exactly is the difference between accessing a file through HTML (e.g. `<img src="xxx.jpg">`) or JavaScript, and using PHP to read a file. The file is still just on the server in both cases, isn't it?

What makes using PHP to access the server's file system different to someone just typing in the URL of the file (provided they know what it is)?

Comment: For starters, a client has to GET the file. Meaning they retrieve a copy from the server. Which is typically cached, so they might not even have the most recent version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static files like (images, HTML, etc) there is no difference, if you directly enter the file URI or read it internally and print the buffer through PHP (at this case the file URI will change for sure).

For dynamic files (PHP files), the same concept is true, if you enter the file URI directly you will get the output of that file, and if you read it internally (There are two types: include and read its source). but in most cases, PHP files are designed for execution not for printing the source, therefore, in both cases:

- When you try to read static files by PHP its just resource wasting if there is no need to use PHP.

Answer (score 2):

**javascript** is client side and runs in the browser.

**php** is server side and runs in the server.

note that there are now server side javascript interpreters like node.js or phantom.js

Comment: ... and? This does not answer the question that was asked :)

Comment: yes,But I try to clarify the basics first. The question is than more "How is a file fastest served, via web server directly or by calling a php script."

Comment: Let the answer follow up then, the basics should be comments if the answer doesn't come with it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the two cases you mentioned the file is on the server. If the file is *static* such as images, you can have its URL directly in the HTML.

In some cases you need to to have a *dynamic URL* for the content, for example a download service that generates a temporary URL for the content after authenticating the user. In such case you would serve the file using PHP since you do not have a fixed URL for the content

Answer (score 0):

Like you are saying, php might really access the FILE SYSTEM, while a client just can access files the Server handles to them.